# char* from char[] member of structure

Tags: c, struct, char

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    LogLevel level;
    char message[255];
} LogMessage;
```

I then have a function which receives a pointer to a LogMessage structure, and needs to call a function that takes in a char*:

```
xStatus = xQueueReceive(xQueueHandleGSMSend, &lReceivedData, portMAX_DELAY);

if(xStatus == pdPASS)
{
    logSimpleMessage(&lReceivedData->message, 1);
}
```

Here is the prototype for the logSimpleMessage function:

```
void logSimpleMessage(const char * message, int level);
```

When I attempt to call it with the above code, I am not getting the correct address (or contents) of the message.  How do I get a char* that points to the message of lReceivedData?

EDIT: I have attempted to use lReceivedData->message, as suggested, but I am still not getting the correct address or values.  Here is a screen cap of the IDE... Am I doing something terribly wrong in the debugger, because it seems as though it should work.

[image]

Comment: What is the value that you are expecting? I can see that the message string is "Check Stack Status" in the debugger.. What is being printed/shown in the logSimpleMessage()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of

```
logSimpleMessage(&lReceivedData->message, 1);
```

you put so:

```
logSimpleMessage(lReceivedData->message, 1);
```

Comment: I have tried this, and attached screenshot to the question with the results, I am still getting a different address.

Comment: in your photo I do not see the address of the message. I see only the content of the message

Comment: are you sure you want to pass as argument the address of the structure by reference, not a duplicate pointer ?

Comment: How would I pass a duplicate pointer, as opposed to the address of the structure?

Comment: it is better to paste the whole code instead of that image, to understand it globally. Otherwise one cannot see what is the problem from what you said. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the photo was more to show the specific address issue, but as you said, the address of the message was not show by the IDE anyways.  Your answer solved the specific question of passing the pointer to the array though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
&lReceivedData->message
```

Produces the address of an array.  An array will decay to a pointer when needed, so simply use :

```
logSimpleMessage(lReceivedData->message, 1);
```

You cannot truly pass an array to a function, the array will always decay to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @Crake: What exactly is "incorrect" about it? When you pass it as an argument a pointer is created.  The *pointer itself* will of course have its own address, but it will point to the first element of the array.

Comment: I think I was looking at the debugger thinking I was passing the actual address, not a new pointer to the address.  Wouldn't the value of the pointer (in the screenshot, in the variables window, "testMessage" is the pointer in the function) be the address of the first element of the array?  In the screenshot, I think maybe the debugger is showing me the address of the pointer and then showing me the actual value of the memory in the pointer location of message, rather than being able to see the address of the message.  This has given me good insight to move forward with, thank you.

Comment: @Crake: The debugger should be showing you the *value* of the pointer, i.e., the address it refers to, not *the address of the pointer itself*.  However, your debug window looks strange to me. I can assure you however that, when you pass an array to a function, a pointer to its first element is what is actually passed.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to pass `lReceivedData->message` to the function, remove the `&`:

```
logSimpleMessage(lReceivedData->message, 1);
```

A type of `char[]` decays to a `char*` when passed to a function.

Comment: @Crake: I'm not sure what the problem you're trying to show in the image is, but this is how you'd pass a `char[]` to a function expecting a `char*`. There must be a problem elsewhere in your code that's causing the array to not be set with the values you're expecting.